# Message box under the web site logo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Is there a way to create a message box under the web site logo icon in a html page, just like the pop up: "This website does not supply identity information; your connection to this website is not encrypted. " when the logo besides the page url is clicked at stackoverflow.

Thanks.

Comment: you can check the last page with document.referrer

Comment: @micha really? Will you show me if I give you *my* html? Here it is: `<html><head/><body></body></html>`.

Comment: No. Those messages are handled by the browser themselves; and can't be accessed via JavaScript, otherwise it'd represent a security flaw.

Comment: you can write an extension for all browsers, then it is working.

Comment: or you can make a popup window.open (but I hate popups and thats why there is a popup blocker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of. Those are browser messages (specifically in Chrome).

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean the little icon left of the name of the page. If so, you know it is displaying the title element of head element. So you can put anything in the title element, but it will show in the browsers header also.

Comment: In which browser? In Firefox 8 it displays `This website does not supply identity information` which is definitely **not** the title of the page.

Comment: ohh he meant the shortcut-icon. Why can't he say that :@ Before you said that I thight it would be possible ;(

Comment: Yes, the shortcut-icon is what i meant, see "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon"

Comment: sorry, i meant the icon left of the name of site

Answer (score 1):

No you can't and to be more specific : No you will NEVER EVER be able to do it.

The little arrow for example in chrome that is present in such messages and messages like "save password" are there for the user to be able to distinguish between the page and the browser telling something (To avoid the page faking a browser message that could lead to bad security consequences)

Comment: Thanks, it is always nice to know.